# Proxypass exclude URLs that ends with a pattern

Tags: regex, apache, proxy, apache2, proxypass

I am trying to configure apache2 proxy settings to

1. Exclude proxying the URLs that has trim=1 flag such that the content is served by apache itself.
2. Proxy URLs that do not have trim=1 flag to a URL http://1.2.3.4:8080/mywebapp/

I have the following settings in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine on
    ProxyPassMatch "(?<=trim=1)$" !
    ProxyPassMatch "(?<!trim=1)$" "http://1.2.3.4:8080/mywebapp/"

</VirtualHost>
```

And I could see that requests with trim=1 flag also gets proxied to http://1.2.3.4:8080/mywebapp/. I tried various settings in regex like lookback and could not get it to work. I would appreciate some help !